# Check dll size in windbg

Tags: c++, windbg

My app is crash. So I am using windbg to check the trace log. Here is my trace log in windbg:

```
FAILED_INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS: 
cbmwk5!unloaded+161c0
727261c0 ??              ???

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17298 (debuggers(dbg).141024-1500) amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 423c1d76 to 72725817

IP_MODULE_UNLOADED: 
cbmwk5!unloaded+15817
72725817 ??              ???

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  BAD_INSTRUCTION_PTR_NULL

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  BAD_INSTRUCTION_PTR_NULL

STACK_TEXT:  
023eebfc 72725817 cbmwk5!unloaded+0x15817
023eec00 423c1d76 unknown!unknown+0x0
023eec30 7272590a cbmwk5!unloaded+0x1590a
023eec58 72723a39 cbmwk5!unloaded+0x13a39
023ef120 76b65762 shell32!SHGetFolderPathW+0x180
023ef128 72720813 cbmwk5!unloaded+0x10813
023ef144 7271110e cbmwk5!unloaded+0x110e
023ef164 72715916 cbmwk5!unloaded+0x5916
023ef59c 7271636b cbmwk5!unloaded+0x636b
```

Could you please help me how to check the size of cbmwk5.dll according to STACK_TEXT?
What is the meaning of "+0x15817" int the statement:

```
023eebfc 72725817 cbmwk5!unloaded+0x15817
```

I tried to reload by using command:

```
.reload /unl cbmwk5.dll
```

and then type: !analyze -v
but the error missing cbmwk5.dll occurs:

```
SYMSRV:  c:\localsymbols\cbmwk5.dll\506DCE083b000\cbmwk5.dll not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/cbmwk5.dll/506DCE083b000/cbmwk5.dll not found
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\cbmwk5.dll - file not found
DBGENG:  cbmwk5.dll - Image mapping disallowed by non-local path.
DBGHELP: No header for cbmwk5.dll.  Searching for dbg file
DBGHELP: .\cbmwk5.dbg - file not found
DBGHELP: .\dll\cbmwk5.dbg - path not found
DBGHELP: .\symbols\dll\cbmwk5.dbg - path not found
DBGHELP: cbmwk5.pdb - file not found
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for cbmwk5.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for cbmwk5.dll
DBGHELP: cbmwk5 - no symbols loaded
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\cbmwk5.dll - file not found
SYMSRV:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x64\sym\cbmwk5.dll\506DCE083b000\cbmwk5.dll not found
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can check the dll size using `lmvm cbmwk5.dll` in the output it will show `ImageSize XXXXXXX` where XXXXXXX will be the size

Comment: Does this fully answer your question? I don't know specifically what `unloaded` means here, it could mean the dll is unloaded or you have a function called unloaded, the following number is the address offset from the base address for that dll but if it's failed to resolve the symbols correctly then this could be garbage

Comment: what is the meaning of "+0x15817" in the statement:  023eebfc 72725817 cbmwk5!unloaded+0x15817

Comment: Saying that `0x15817` is quite a large offset which I think is unlikely to be a real address as this is 88087 bytes so unless you have a shedload public methods with a complicated class hierarchy this could be bogus, also the next line reads `unknown!unknown+0x0` which to me looks like you can't rely on this stack trace too much

Comment: Actually it shows the text `IP_MODULE_UNLOADED: 
cbmwk5!unloaded+15817` so can you force it load this module: `.reload /unl cbmwk5.dll`

Comment: Yes, I forced it load this module by using your comment. and type !analyze -v. The error of missing cbmwk5.dll appears: DBGHELP: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\cbmwk5.dll - file not found
DBGENG:  cbmwk5.dll - Image mapping disallowed by non-local path.
DBGHELP: No header for cbmwk5.dll.  Searching for dbg file
DBGHELP: .\cbmwk5.dbg - file not found
DBGHELP: .\dll\cbmwk5.dbg - path not found
DBGHELP: .\symbols\dll\cbmwk5.dbg - path not found
DBGHELP: cbmwk5.pdb - file not found

Comment: Can you edit this into the post, thanks

Answer (score 4):

> What is the meaning of "+0x15817" int the statement

+0x15817 means that the debugger has no clue whatsoever which function was called.  It just doesn't know anything about the DLL, only where it was once loaded.  So it can only annotate the address with the DLL name and a very large offset.  Otherwise visible from the SYMSRV trace messages, the debugger made an attempt to download the PDB file for the DLL but the symbol server doesn't know anything about the DLL.  Which is certainly not unusual, it is a 3rd party DLL, not Microsoft's.  Even Google has never heard of it.

> FAILED_INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS:
>  
>   cbmwk5!unloaded+161c0

The `unloaded` annotation is your strongest clue to the problem.  The code crashed because the DLL was unloaded from memory.  Yet the program tried to call it anyway.  With no code left to execute (note the `??`), the processor is forced to give up and generates an access violation.  That was the end of the program, it cannot continue operating.

> 023ef120 76b65762 shell32!SHGetFolderPathW+0x180

The stack trace gives a (weak) clue to the underlying problem.  Beware that this is speculation.  But the presence of shell function like SHGetFolderPathW() is a strong hint that this is a misbehaving shell extension.  They can do a lot of damage since they tend to be injected into your program when you use one of the common shell dialogs, like OpenFileDialog.  In other words, it doesn't have anything to do with *your* program, it is somebody else's crappy code that made the program bomb.

You fix this kind of problem by disabling shell extensions one by one until the problem disappears.  SysInternals' AutoRuns utility is the weapon of choice.  It has to be done by the machine owner, there's little that you can do but give advice.

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant a lot